# composite Primairy Key postgres ( same value for one PK)

Tags: database, postgresql, relational-database, database-schema, postgresql-9.3

I 'm facing this situation :

[image]

`r_owner` is a Foreign Key in the table `r_contact`.
I'm thinking to set (iD)"r_contact" and (r_owner)"r_contact" as PK. My question is if I do it , can r_owner take the same value for different instance of the `r_contact` table?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why would you do so? ID would be enough for a primary key, because it is supposed to be unique. Moreover, it will probably require an additional index on two fields - ID and R_Owner (which is bigger then just an ID index).
The composite key you have proposed is usually applied to N-to-M relations, which is not your case.

Anyway, answer to your question is "yes". You will be able to have duplicate r_owner values in r_contract as long, as ID's are unique.

Comment: Thanks a lot smytkin_max understood, I will set r_owner as an index.
can you please give me one example, when composite pack is required.
thanks in advance

Comment: Lets say, here is a Student relation (Student_ID is primary key), Course relation (Course_ID is primary key).
And there is Student_courses relation, which lists all the courses for all the student. It has two foreign keys: Student_ID and Course_ID. And they form a composite primary key.

Comment: Thanks a lot smytkin_max

Comment: Also, sometimes it's okay to add a composite primary key on a relation itself (without any foreign keys), if you're sure that it's unique and you need to index it anyway.
For example, if first_name + second_name are 100% unique in your DB and you often search by first_name + second_name, than you may save you some performance, making them primary key (and you don't need ID at all).
But it's really an overcomplicated example and you probably shouldn't think about it, yet.